# authentication flow in dropwizard

Tags: java, rest, authentication, dropwizard

I have gone through many forum to understand the flow but still confuse with the correct flow.

I am using Dropwizard and First I wanted to get token from REST API (Username & password will be provided in Basic auth) then next time this token will be pass in every request.

**Main Class**

```
    environment.jersey()
                .register(
                        new AuthDynamicFeature(
                                new JwtAuthFilter.Builder<User>()
                                        .setAuthenticator(new MarginCalcAuthenticator())
                                        .setAuthorizer(
                                                new CalcAuthorizer())
                                        .setRealm("BASIC-AUTH-REALM")
                                        .buildAuthFilter()));
environment.jersey().register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
        environment.jersey().register(new AuthValueFactoryProvider.Binder<User>(User.class));
```

**AuthFilter**

```
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class JwtAuthFilter<P extends Principal> extends AuthFilter<JWTCredentials, P> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthFilter.class);
    public static final String AUTHENTICATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String authCredentials = requestContext.getHeaderString(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER);
```

**Authenticator**

```
public class CalcAuthenticator implements Authenticator<JWTCredentials, User> {

    public Optional<User> authenticate(JWTCredentials credentials)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        AdminAuthenticationService authService = new AdminAuthenticationService();

        User userObj = authService.authenticate(credentials.getJwtToken());
        if (userObj == null) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        return Optional.of(userObj);
    }

}
```

**REST API Resource class**

```
@GET
    @Path("token")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response genToken(@Context SecurityContext sc){
        return Response
                .ok()
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+AdminAuthenticationService.issueToken((br.dc.auth.User) sc
                        .getUserPrincipal())).build();
    }
```

I am debugging from Postman and it is hitting my API genToken but it never came to JwtAuthFilter or CalcAuthenticator. Can anyone help me to understand the flow ? I want to understand the flow.

Comment: Is the class or method annotated with `@RolesAllowed` (or any other authz anno)? The auth is only done on methods (or classes) you tell it to.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I forgot to add it. Now it is hitting AuthFilter and I am able to authenticate but I am still confuse with the flow. It is hitting only AuthFilter but still I dont know when CalcAuthenticator will get call. Can I use only CalcAuthenticator or only AuthFilter ? Which one will be preferred ? If I want both then ?

Comment: You need to call the `authenticate()` method of the `AuthFilter`. Look at the [basic auth filter](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/basic/BasicCredentialAuthFilter.java) and [AuthFilter](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-auth/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/auth/AuthFilter.java). You should get an idea of the flow and what you need to do with your own implementation of the AuthFilter

Comment: Thank you for providing these details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul mention class or method annotated with @RolesAllowed (or any other authz anno) is required for authentication. The auth is only done on methods (or classes) you tell it to.

**Flow**
Register your filter, Authenticator etc with the Environment -> start your server -> request the token from UI or postman -> It will hit your AuthFilter -> You can call your authenticator for token validation -> Authenticate your request and send the response accordingly.